# KOMA-script: How to let one specific chapter start on even page?

Tags: page-breaking, koma-script

In `\documentclass{scrbook}` chapters use to start on odd pages. However I want one specific chapter (only this one) to start on an even page. How can I realize this?

**MWE**

In the following example chapter 3 should start on an even page.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\chapter{bla} % should start on odd page
\blindtext[8]

\chapter{bla bla} % should start on odd page
\blindtext[3]

\chapter{bla bla bla} % should start on EVEN page
\blindtext[8]

\chapter{bla bla bla} % should start on odd page
\blindtext[8]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`\KOMAoption`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#desc:maincls.cmd.KOMAoption) or [`\KOMAoptions`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#desc:maincls.cmd.KOMAoptions) command to change the setting of option [`open`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#desc:maincls.option.open) inside the document:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\chapter{bla} % should start on odd page
\blindtext[8]

\chapter{bla bla} % should start on odd page
\blindtext[3]

\KOMAoptions{open=left}
\chapter{bla bla bla} % should start on EVEN page
\blindtext[8]

\KOMAoption{open}{right}% or immediate after the previous \chapter{bla bla bla}
\chapter{bla bla bla} % should start on odd page
\blindtext[8]

\end{document}
```